# First app for android after eclipse install

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've searched around and can't quite find the exact situation or answer that I need, so I'll have to ask a question that I'm sure has been asked somewhere out there, so my apologies. But I need help.
First time attempting to create an app, I installed Eclipse (both the entire kit from the android development site, and classic), installed the android sdk, and the plugin. Java is on my machine. I have everything that I need to get started. I was going through the tutorials on the android developer site for the first time user. Eclipse generates the "hello world" app as it should. I have my GS3 plugged in through USB with the driver installed and the system sees it. I click run as > android application... and to no surprise, nothing happens. No error message, no screen flash, no app on the device, nothing. So I tried to run it in an emulator. Not too clear how to set it up because the instructions are vague, but I got an emulator going and try to run again... nothing. No attempts to and then fails, no build errors.. no quick command prompt flashes, just nothing. The IDE just sits there as if I never clicked anything. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for helping

My current setup is
Win8 machine
Eclipse Classic (because the one provided on the site wouldn't install the plugin)
Android SDK 21.1
Eclipse Plugin for Android dev
Java JDK 1.7
Samsung Galaxy S3 device with driver installed and set to USB debugging

Comment: How did you generate the "Hello World" app? Are you sure it's an Android app?

Comment: Did you turn on Developer options in your GS3?

Comment: Try this: Run As -> Run Configurations -> Target -> Always prompt to pick device -> Then start a new emulator. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to enable developer option (USB Debugging), then connect your device, now check whether adb recognise your device or not.

to check device status open DDMS perspective then click on Devices option. if your device is not listed, then restart your adb to do that go to adb path in command prompt/terminal then execute following commands

**adb kill-server**

**adb start-server**

**adb devices**

that's it now you can run application in your device